# Can values from dropdownlists in detailsview be updated without autopostback?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I have a details view that is in "insert Mode" so the user just sees blank spaces to enter values.  I have two drop down lists and I wanted to have the second ddl change its value by what was selected in the first ddl.  I tried setting ddl1 to a label so ddl2 would change when the label changed.  The problem I am having now is that I need autopostback to update the value of the label, but selecting "autopostback" on the ddl1 makes my code throw a data binding error.

I was wondering if there was any way I could get around using autopostback and still update values selected in the first ddl to the label.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *AjaxControlToolkit*. It has a feature to cascade ddlists. Use updatepanel as container for both of ddls so you can omit autopostback.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not completely clear. But if you want to change the dd2 value on change event of dd1, you can use the following code:

$("#<%= statusDDL.ClientID %>").val($("#<%= dd1.ClientID %>option:selected").text() );

It is not clear whether you want value or text property.
Also I am not 100% that this syntax will work. But obviously it can be done using this concept searching on net for your requirement